# MacRuby + Interface Builder: How to display, then close, then display a window again

Tags: xcode, data-binding, interface-builder, macruby, window-management

I'm a complete n00b with MacRuby and Cocoa, so keep that in mind when answering - I need lots of details and explanation. :)

I've set up a simple project that has 2 windows in it, both of which are built with Interface Builder. The first window is a simple list of accounts using a table view. It has a "+" button below the table. When I click the + button, I want to show an "Add New Account" window.

I also have an `AccountsController < NSWindowController` and a `AddNewAccountController < NSWindowController` class, set up as the delegates for these windows, with the appropriate button click methods wired up, and outlets to reference the needed windows.

When I click the "+" button in the Accounts window, I have this code fire:

```
    @add_account.center
    @add_account.display
    @add_account.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    @add_account.orderFrontRegardless
```

this works great the first time I click the + button. Everything shows up, I'm able to enter my data and have it bind to my model. however, when I close the add new account form, things start going bad.

if I set the add new account window to release on close, then the second time I click the + button, the window will still pop up but it's frozen. i can't click any buttons, enter any data, or even close the form. i assume this is because the form's code has been released, so there is no message loop processing the form... but i'm not entirely sure about this.

if i set the add new account window to not release on close, then the second time i click the + button, the window shows up fine and it is usable - but it still has all the data that i had previously entered... it's still bound to my previous Account class instance.

what am I doing wrong? what's the correct way to create a new instance of the Add New Account form, create a new Account model, bind that model to the form and show the form, when I click the + button on the Accounts form?

... this is all being done on OSX 10.6.6, 64bit, with XCode 3.2.4

Comment: Have you connected other elements to the controller (buttons/textareas)? I had trouble following tutorials which show nsobjects dropdown menu to controller messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that it doesn't create the window each time. Release on close is a bit of an annoying option and generally is only used if you know the window controller is also being released when the window closes. (Note I've never used MacRuby so I'll be giving code in Obj-C as I know that it is correct, hopefully you can convert it. I'll be assuming GC is on as it should be with MacRuby).

Now there are two ways to do this. I'm not entirely sure how your NIB/classes are set up as it could be one of two ways.

--

The first way to solve it is to use the outlets you use to reference the form elements to blank them out when you display the window again eg [myTextField setStringValue:@""]. If you're using cocoa bindings then it's a little trickier, but basically you have to make sure the bound object is blanked out. I would recommend against bindings though if you are new to Cocoa.

--

The second way is to make the AddNewAccountController class a subclass of NSWindowController. When you press the + button you would then create a new instance of it and display it (remember to store it in an ivar). The best way to do it would be as so:

```
if (!addAccountController) {
    addAccountController = [[AddNewAccountController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"AddNewAccountController"];
    [[addAccountController window] setDelegate:self];
}
[addAccountController showWindow:self];
```

This prevents a new instance being made if the window is already visible. You then need to implement the delegate:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //If you don't create the account in the AddNewAccountController then do it here
    addAccountController = nil;
}
```

Obviously you would need to move the window to a separate NIB called "AddNewAccountController". In this NIB make sure to set the class of the File's Owner to AddNewAccountController and then to connect the File's Owner's window outlet to the window.

When all this is set up, you will get a fresh controller/window each time. It also has the benefit of splitting up nibs and controllers into more focused units.

--

One last thing. While it is fine to do something like this in a window, you may want to eventually look at doing this via a sheet, as it would then prevent the possibility of the add account window getting hidden behind other windows.

Comment: nothing is obvious with me, in xcode. :) so, a .xib file is a NIB, right? i should organize all of my interface elements that are related to each other in separate NIBs - a window and a menu, the controllers and other objects - instead of in 1 like i'm doing now? that would give me better control over what is loaded, when... and all UI elements in a NIB are created when a NIB is loaded... and i could use awakeFromNib to instantiate my model and bind it to the window's .datasource. does that sound right?

Comment: also - the windowWillClose notification... should that be in the add new account controller? or the accounts controller? i would think in the accounts controller, because that is where i'm using the addNewAccountcontroller variable. but i don't see how i can get the windowWillClose notification from the AddNewAccount window in here.

Comment: interesting note... i see what you mean about using an ivar, now (an instance var, or @var in ruby talk). if i use a standard variable declared within the method that instantiates the controller, the window will live for as long as it has focus. once the window loses focus, it falls out of scope and garbage collection is allowed to reclaim it because there is no in-scope reference to it anymore, and poof - the window closes. :P

Comment: Yeah, xib is just the new file format for nibs while editing. You should try to split things up where you can. The best lines are along window and view controllers, each should have their own nib. As for instantiating your model, it depends on how your app is structured. I can't really say without seeing the whole Xcode project. Ideally you should only create the model when the user confirms the add.

Comment: And the windowWillClose delegate method goes in the accounts controller. It gets called on there due to the [[addNewAccountController window] setDelegate:self] line, which tells the window to put the accounts controller as the delegate.

Comment: re: model instantiation. i'm not using core data at this point. this is strictly a view model that has behavior related to the view, only. once i verify a few bits in this model, i pass it off to a core data model to persist

Comment: re: windowWillClose. Ok, I think i'm missing something here.  where does that first chunk of code you posted, go? i have that inside the add_new_clicked method (the method that handles clicking the + button on the Accounts controller). how would the AddNewAccountController have access to this variable?

Comment: Both chunks of code go in the same class. The first chunk goes in your action, as you have it now and the second chunk is another method somewhere else in the same class.